# How to add leading zero padding with the specified number of digits in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have `data.txt` file as below.

```
12, 345, 6789
```

Now, I want to perform leading zero padding with the specified number of digits in the specified field of the argument file or standard input.
The number of digits specified in the specified field of the argument file is 8 digits.
What should I do?

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._  
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

//Convert textfile to DF
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ct").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val sc = SparkContext(conf)
val sparkSess = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkSessionZipsExample").config(conf).getOrCreate()
val path = "data.txt"
val data = sc.textFile(path)
val colNum = data.first().split(",").size
var schemaString = "key"
for( i <- 1 to colNum - 1) {
 schemaString += " value" + i
}
val fields = schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable=true))
val schema = StructType(fields)
val dfWithSchema = sparkSess.read.option("header", "false").schema(schema).csv(path)
dfWithSchema.show()

//add leading zero padding with the specified number of digits
//The number of digits specified in the specified field of the argument file is 8 digits
val df = dfWithSchema.withColumn("key", format_string("%08d", $"key")).show
val df2 = dfWithSchema.withColumn("value2", format_string("%08d", $"value2")).show
```

But the output result is incorrect.

I want to have the desired output result as below. Please help me.

```
+---------+------+---------+
|key      |value1|value2   |
+---------+------+---------+
| 00000012|   345| 00006789|
+---------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the build-in `lpad` function as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lpad

dfWithSchema.select(
  lpad($"key", 8, "0", 
  lpad($"value2", 8, "0"),
  $"value1"
).show
```

This will insert 0s in the front of the string for a maximum of 8 characters.

Please refer [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/sql/#lpad) for details.

Comment: Hi @Alexandros Biratsisthis, This result output is missing the value of column`value1`? please update code help me.

Comment: Hi John value1 doesn't change you can include it in your select statement as I did above, please check the modified version

Comment: Hi @Alexandros Biratsisthis, Thank you very much. good solution!